# Docker compose [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to develop a Django application with Nginx and dockerize it. When running the docker compose I am getting the error

```
proxy_1  | 2020/08/05 21:34:49 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
proxy_1  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
django_proj_proxy_1 exited with code 1
```

This is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV TZ=America/New_York
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y  python3-pip  python-dev && \
    apt-get install -y wget


RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip


ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt


RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        volumes:
            - static_data:/vol/web 
        environment:
            - SECRET_KEY=samplesecretkey123
            - ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1, localhost, 0.0.0.0 
        
    proxy:
        build:
            context: ./proxy
        volumes:    
            - static_data:/vol/static
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        depends_on: 
            - app 

volumes:
    static_data:
```

I also have a folder named proxy which contains
default.conf, Dockerfile, uwsgi_params in the same directory.

default.config:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass app:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine 

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static
RUN chmod 755 /vol/static

USER nginx
```

Comment: Is the Python server expecting UWSGI or HTTP? If the latter, you should be using `proxy_pass` instead of `uwsgi_pass`.

Comment: i tried with proxy_pass and it didn't work.

Comment: I had the same error, following the same example/tutorial you did. Saving all files changed solved the problem for me... quite weird tbh